# GeoServer Printing Extension and MapBox's new API

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, printing, mapfish

I'm using MapBox as a basemap, and the GeoServer Printing Extension for printing this and some layers out of GeoServer.

I now have it working for the old MapBox API (with URLs like `https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, but it seems that the GeoServer Printing Extension doesn't like handling tile URLs without an extension, like the new MapBox API uses, e.g, `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}`. The GeoServer Printing Extension really wants an extension. Leaving the extension blank doesn't work, as it still puts a dot on there.

So, my question is, can the GeoServer Printing Extension handle a XYZ tile service without an extension, or is there a way to add an extension to the new MapBox API?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the XYZ layer type. This can take the optional `path_format` which I configured like this:

```
path_format = '${z}/${x}/${y}'
```

and that builds the proper URL.